# TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, vector) (of Variable Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float64, matrix)

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network

I am using theano and their LeNet tutorial to train CNN with the dataset of Street View Google Images.

I load the dataset:

```
train_set_x, train_set_y, \
valid_set_x, valid_set_y, \
test_set_x, test_set_y = manager.get_grayscale_data_dim()
```

I get the dimensions printed:

```
self.train_data_dims (70000, 1024, 1)
self.train_labels_dims (70000, 1)
self.valid_data_dims (3250, 1024, 1)
self.valid_labels_dims (3250, 1)
self.test_data_dims (26000, 1024, 1)
self.test_labels_dims (26000, 1)
```

Then I do as in tutorial:

```
# allocate symbolic variables for the data
index = T.lscalar()  # index to a [mini]batch
x = T.matrix('x')   # the data is presented as rasterized images
y = T.ivector('y')  # the labels are presented as 1D vector of

print "y.type", y.type, "y.ndim", y.ndim
print "test_set_y", test_set_y.type, "test_set_y.ndim", test_set_y.ndim
```

Result printed:

```
y.type TensorType(int64, vector) y.ndim 1
test_set_y TensorType(int64, vector) test_set_y.ndim 1
```

I get the problem here (this is the first function defined, next is validation and traning, just so that the name does not confuse you, and you don't think that everything went OK with similar training and validation functions):

## create a function to compute the mistakes that are made by the model

```
test_model = theano.function(
    [index],
    layer3.errors(y),
    givens={
        x: test_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: test_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

Precisely, I have an error in line:

```
y: test_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
```

The error itself says (afaiu) that I am trying to convert smth to matrix.
Where is this happening, I wonder?

```
TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, vector) (of Variable Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float64, matrix). You can try to manually convert Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(float64, matrix).
```

AFAIU, the dimensions of y and test_set_y agree. In my code, they are both 1D vectors.
**Why does slicing cause error? Does slicing create matrix? And more importantly, how do I solve this problem?**
Thanks in advance!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Flatten your array

```
 y_out = theano.shared(np.asarray(y, dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
 y_out = y_out.flatten()
 y_out = T.cast(y_out, 'int32')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input data looks strange and, specifically, the labels are presented as matrices, not vectors.

```
self.train_data_dims (70000, 1024, 1)
self.train_labels_dims (70000, 1)
self.valid_data_dims (3250, 1024, 1)
self.valid_labels_dims (3250, 1)
self.test_data_dims (26000, 1024, 1)
self.test_labels_dims (26000, 1)
```

Why do all of these have an extra dimension of size one at the end?

I think you need to change your data loading code so this prints

```
self.train_data_dims (70000, 1024, 1)
self.train_labels_dims (70000, )
self.valid_data_dims (3250, 1024, 1)
self.valid_labels_dims (3250, )
self.test_data_dims (26000, 1024, 1)
self.test_labels_dims (26000, )
```

This ensure that, for example, `test_labels` is a vector instead of a matrix.

Comment: I added an extra dimension to `self.train_data_dims (70000, 1024, 1)` and other variables to make it consistent with the RGB images case where the dimensions would be (70000, 1024, 3), the last one corresponding to RGB channels. Also, in the tutorial they give, they reshape the X matrix in a way: `layer0_input = x.reshape((batch_size, 1, image_rows, images_cols))`, where `1` specifies the depth of an image. I tried with `0`, didn't work. Also, the convolution itself is performed across the whole depth of an image (depth=3 in RGB case), AFAIK.

Comment: Why can't the labels vector be a matrix of a size (nx1)? Anyway, the dimensions of labels I get is `1`. So aren't the labels being treated already as a vector? Even though at the beginning of the code it looks like they are in (nx1) matrix, and I don't quite undrestand the difference between such matrix and a vector, except  the latter has 1 less dimension specified..

Comment: Okay, so no need to change the data itself but the labels do need to be a vector. In Theano a tensor with shape `(1, N)` or `(N, 1)` is a matrix (i.e. it has 2 dimensions; that one is of size 1 is irrelevent). Since your code contains `y = T.ivector('y')` the labels need to be presented as vectors, not as matrices.

Comment: `test_set_y.type TensorType(int32, vector)` and `y.type TensorType(int32, vector)` are of the same type. However, this line of code causes error: `y: test_set_y_vec[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]`. I can't solve it. I tried already explicitly declaring test_set_y as a `T.iscalar` and `fill` to set the values. Doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: Can you replace the real data with random values and cut your script down to the minimum amount that still exhibits the problem, so it can be posted in full here?